# Function that returns the string representation of a value

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a variable of type `[Character]`, bound to name `chars`:

```swift
chars = Array("Hello World")
```

A function that returns the string representation of any type that conform to `LosslessStringConvertible` could be:

```swift
func show<A: LosslessStringConvertible>(_ x: A) -> String {
    return String(x)
}
```

However, when I call the function:

```swift
show(chars)
```

the following error message appears...

```swift
Global function 'show' requires that '[Character]' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'
```

On the other hand, simply calling `String` function, works:

```swift
String(chars)
```

Does `String` function have any additional constrains ? How can I modify my function in order to accomplish this goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs/says because/that `Character` does not conform to `LosslessStringConvertible`

`CustomStringConvertible` is more versatile

```
func show<A: CustomStringConvertible>(_ x: A) -> String {
    return String(describing: x)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @gcharita. I found out that quote, too.

Comment: Thank you, @vadian. In a recent test, I noticed `show(["1", "2"])` returns `["1", "2"]`, and I would like `"12"`. Is there a way to accomplish that ?

Comment: An array `shows` an array. To flatten the array you have to call `joined()`: `show(["1", "2"].joined())`

Comment: I missed your response. Thank you, @vadian !